# How to solve the error "ncview: can't recognize format of input file " in centos7

Tags: linux, centos, command-line

I tried to visualize my `WRF-Chem output` file `wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00` using `ncview` after moving the file to the `/run/media/maslab-3/exthdd` directory where my 8 TB external HDD is mounted.

But when I gave the command `ncview wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00` the following error came:

```
ncview: can't recognize the format of the input file wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00
```

However, the same file was in a different folder, and when I gave the same command, it was working.

I noticed that all the files in the `/run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/` directory are green-colored. However, when the same files are placed in the other directories, they are white-colored, i.e., normal files. I noticed earlier that when I used the command `chmod +x *filename*`, the files turned green. So normally, green-colored files are executable files. I thought after using `chmod a-x wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00`, it would work. But it didn't.

When I gave the command `file wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00`, it returned the following line

```
wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00: data
```

So, can anyone help me figure out how to solve this? That will be very helpful for me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you try to check file "original file" as gcode should be text. probably there is a mistake during the copy.

Comment: I don't understand this part "Can you try to check file "original file" as gcode should be text". Can you please elaborate on it a little bit? That will be very helpful.

Comment: can you perform a { file original file} as normally nc code should be revealed as text and not data.

Comment: This is the original file 'wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00:00:00', which is the output of WRF-Chem and I renamed this to 'wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00_00_00' for successfully copying the file in the  /run/media/maslab-3/exthdd/ directory (since filename with colon is not supported in the NTFS or FAT drive). However, even if I performed "file wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00:00:00", it returned the same thing "wrfout_d01_2015-12-25_00:00:00: data". And it is returning the same irrespective of the directory in which it is placed. But, the command 'ncview' is only working in other directories, not in /exthdd/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the wrfout file name with .nc for ncview to read it.